# Sum and Ceiling in Linq to Entities

Tags: mysql, linq-to-entities

What is the way to code this query with Linq to Entities (method based syntax)?

```
select sum(ceiling((PackSize)/50)) from table1;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = context.Table1.Sum(x => Math.Ceiling(x.PackSize/50));
```

Comment: Thank you, i was not sure where to put the Ceiling function.